# How to silence #pragma messages from GCC

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, pragma, suppress-warnings

I am not interested in seeing `#pragma message`s for my build. It just clutters the output.

I tell this to Clang by passing `-Wno-#pragma-messages`. However, GCC does not understand that flag and I can not find any similar flag.

How do I ask GCC to ignore `#pragma message`?

Comment: From manual: "-Wno-pragmas -- Do not warn about misuses of pragmas, such as incorrect parameters, invalid syntax, or conflicts between pragmas. See also -Wunknown-pragmas."
#pragma message is not misuse, hence this flag not the right one. Further, I need a solution that just target #pragma messages not other #pragmas.

Comment: I misunderstood. If you have: `#pragma clang ...` for example, `-Wno-unknown-pragmas` should suppress the message. If you pass an invalid pragma via `#pragma GCC ...`, that's a hard error, and you will need something like `#if ... #endif` guards.