# Declaring Clang’s -fno-caret-diagnostics only for a specific type of #pragma

Tags: c, clang, pragma

I rely on Clang’s `#pragma message` to remember TODO notices. For example,

```
int
main(void)
{
#pragma message "TODO: do something"
}
```

which gives this output for `clang -o todo todo.c`:

```
todo.c:4:9: warning: TODO: do something [-W#pragma-messages]
#pragma message "TODO: do something"
        ^
1 warning generated.
```

This, however, is redundant. I know I can use the `-fno-caret-diagnostics` flag with Clang to avoid having the `#pragma` line in the compiler’s output, but this also disables the caret diagnostics for other warnings and errors, which I would want to avoid.

Is there a way of declaring `-fno-caret-diagnostics` only for this kind of `#pragma`?

Comment: Is there a reason why you cant write `// TODO` and then do a text search through the project? Too easy?

Comment: Extending on @Lundin's comment: Basically an XY-Problem. Some editors like kwrite highlight such comments (`// TODO`, `// NOTE`, etc.). Also doxygen (which should be used anyway in a larger project) collects `todo` tagged paragraphs and presents them in a seperate chapter.

Comment: You are right. `// TODO` is a better way of doing what I intend, because of compatibility reasons, and also, now that I think about it, because relying only on `#pragma message` seems inadvisable with incremental compilation.

Comment: I'm also interested in this. I have a project which I need to issue informational messages at compile time hence `#pragma message`. Just that, like the O.P., I'd like to avoid them as they add confusion when the message contains (expanded) macros.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, the answer is part of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31669021/how-to-silence-pragma-messages-from-gcc). Does `-Wno#pragma-messages` do what you want?

Comment: No, `-Wno-#pragma-messages` hides all output from these `#pragma`s, while the goal would be to print these messages without also showing their source in the code.

However, @Lundin and @Olaf’s comments above showed me that what I was asking for is not the best way to keep track of TODOs.